# writeerrorexception using measure-command in ucs vcheck report

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get this powershell report to work

https://github.com/FooBartn/vCheck-UCS

and the report works fine testing it in powershell ise. But when I try to schedule it using powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File

I see the error below

```
C:\Scripts\ucs-vcheck-sdc\Plugins\00
Initialize\00_Connection_Plugin_for_UCS.ps1 : Exception of type
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException' was thrown.
At C:\Scripts\ucs-vcheck-sdc\vcheck.ps1:672 char:59
+ ... TR = [math]::round((Measure-Command {$Details = . $_.FullName}).Total 
...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
tion
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
n,00_Connection_Plugin_for_UCS.ps1

C:\Scripts\ucs-vcheck-sdc\vcheck.ps1 :
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
tion
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
n,vcheck.ps1
```

The code being used is

```
 $TTR = [math]::round((Measure-Command {$Details = . $_.FullName}).TotalSeconds, 2)
```

the basics of the scripts is the main vcheck script call plugins from a folder.And example of what $_.Fullname is

```
C:\Scripts\ucs-vcheck-sdc\Plugins\80 Finish\999 VeryLastPlugin Used to Disconnect.ps1
```

This line is actually what runs the plugins.From my research its a problem writing to the standard output, but I can't seem to locate the problem. I've looked at permissions, and I've removed the spaces from some of the other plugins but it doesn't seem to matter. I'm reaching out to the mainainter, but I wanted to see if anyone had an idea of what would be causing this.

Comment: Have you tried the script in `$_.Fullname`? [The error is saying a `Write-Error` message was triggered](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.writeerrorexception(v=vs.85).aspx). But because it's in another script, it's not writing the actual error or specifying where it is in that script.

Comment: No, good call, there are alot but I got lucky. In the first script there is a section where it checked to see if the module was loaded and if not it loaded it. I found a small typo which fixed that error. Thank you

# Load UCS Powertool Module 
If (!(Get-Module -name Cisco.UCSManager -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    Import-Module Cisco.UCSManager
    
    If (!(Get-Module -name Cisco.UCSManager -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
  Write-Error $pLang.loadModFailed
  Throw
    } Else {
        Write-CustomOut $pLang.LoadModSuccess
    }
}